# How to manage a lot of items on conveyors

Tags: unity, 2d, gameobject

I am making some sort of factory game (topdown 2D) where I will have machines outputting items on conveyors. I was wondering what was the best approach to manage the items on the conveyors.
There are two things that I'm not sure what the best way to achieve them is:

- managing the distance between the items
- moving the items

I think it's best to avoid having a rigid body on every items, as it would probably cause lag on for a mobile game if there are a lot of items. I wanted to avoid having colliders but that may make it too difficult.

I was thinking of having a list on each machine containing the items of all the conveyors connected to it and checking the distance between every item and the one in front of it then moving the items if possible at every update. I'm just not sure if that's the good way of doing things or if there is an obvious solution I haven't thought of (which is most likely the case).

Comment: Are you brave enough to deal with the [Entity-Component-System architecture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.9/manual/index.html)? It would be ideal for a case like this where you have a huge number of very simple objects. But it is still very much in beta.

Comment: Also, does your game world have a clearly defined map size or is it endless? I could think of a couple optimizations, but they would get a lot more complicated in an endless world.

Comment: the world but it's large

Comment: And I'm not sure to be that brave...

Comment: [We have some past Q&A about managing large quantities of object interactions in sim/management games](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/172275/39518) which might be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should know that Factorio is one of the few game projects where the technical requirements are so unusual that writing a custom engine actually made sense. The core of Factorio is written in C++, and the developers are using a lot of low-level optimization tricks to make that humongous number of entities moving around and doing stuff in a large-scale factory work as well as it does. Their [development blog](https://www.factorio.com/blog/40) (linking to the beginning) is a really interesting read for every game developer.

That being said, it should be possible to create a similar game experience in Unity, as long as you are willing to make a couple concessions to the size of factories and the number of items moving around them.

But you will still have to do a couple optimizations, because representing every single item as a full-fledged gameObject will create far too much overhead.

The [entity-component-system architecture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.9/manual/index.html) would be great for this use-case, but it is still in beta and we already established in the comments that you don't feel brave enough to face it in its current state. Which I fully understand after doing a couple experiments in it myself.

But we can still apply a couple of its principles in the regular Unity architecture.

### Logical representation

For example, instead of each item being represented with a gameObject with a transform, a rigidbody and a collider, we can represent it with a plain old C# object and have each conveyor belt own a couple of those. And the conveyor belts themselves could also be represented by plain old C# objects owned by a global `BeltSystem` `MonoBehaviour`. This system could store all the belts in a two-dimensional array with tile indices mapping to array indices. That makes it very easy to acquire the belt on a specific tile and then the items currently on that belt.

### Visual representation

But you still need to render all those belts and items.

The belts don't move (although they might be animated) and are arranged in a grid, which means that using a [Tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tilemap.html) is likely the most optimized way of rendering them.

But for the items you are going to need SpriteRenderers, which require GameObjects. But you only need those for those items which are actually on the screen. So it might be possible to decouple the logical representation of items from their visual representation by having an object with a SpriteRenderer following the position of each item currently on a belt which is on-screen.

But `Instantiate`ing and `Destroy`ing objects frequently also causes performance issues due to the garbage and memory fragmentation they cause. A good way to handle this problem could be to use an [object pool](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling) of objects with SpriteRenderers attached. When a belt or items is on-screen, you request a render-object from the object pool. When the item is destroyed or moves off-screen, you return that render-object back to the pool.

---

I wish you the best of luck with your project. You are going to need it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions / infos. I think that the way I was planning to do it is close to the logical representation. The way I made my conveyors is by having a conveyor script on the main object with an array containing every pieces of the conveyor. For the items I was planning on creating an array of Item+Conveyor to assign them to which piece of conveyor they are to move them to the next one if the conveyor parts array. I like the idea of using Tilemap for the conveyor and i'll look into the idea of destroying whats not visible to the player. Thanks again !